# Applying functions to a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I have a list of values saved in 'survieF.csv' as given below:
The first row contains time in years (1 yr, 3yrs, 5 yrs, and 10 yrs) and the second row contains the name of the variable in the first column and the survival rate in the remaining 4 columns.

```
         1      3    5    10
 var1   0.9   0.85  0.83  0.81
 var2   0.87  0.86  0.84  0.81
 var3   0.79  0.77  0.75  0.72

survieF<-read.csv("SurvieF.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE)
```

In the code given below, for instance,

```
S<-survieF[3,2:5]
x<-c(1,3,5,10)
```

Function:

```
f <- function(ab){
a <- ab[1]
b <- ab[2]
return(sum((exp(a*x**b)-S)**2))
}
```

Finding parameters that minimise my sum using nlm function :

```
minim <- nlm(f,p=c(1,0))

ab <- minim$estimate

a_opt <- ab[1]
b_opt <- ab[2]
```

Using optimal parameters to get vaues:

```
prediction_exp <- function(x){
return(exp(a_opt*x**b_opt))}
```

I then use the parameters to estimate survival rates for 1 to 20 years.

```
survieFcan<-prediction_exp(1:20)
```

However, I want to be able to automatically run the code on each line of my dataframe 'survieF' and then export all the values estimated from year 1 to year 20 on excel. How can I do that?

Comment: A couple of comments: (i) if your CSV file contains the data you show at the top (i.e. 2 rows with semicolon separated values, where the values are on the first row and the name of the values are on the second row), you won't read the *values* into `survieF` because by default `header=TRUE` in `read.csv()` and the values will be read as column *names*; (ii) what's the purpose of the loop where you create `S`? The value of `S` is assigned to row `n` since it's overwritten at every iteration...

Comment: Hello. I have edited my question. I actually want to be run the code on every row of my data frame, hence the loop on S..

Answer (score 0):

The trick to run `nlm()` on every row of `survieF` is to use `apply()` with an **inline function** as its third argument receiving suitable parameters and calling `nlm()`.

The following example illustrates this:

```
#--- 1) Read the data
# Note:
# - the use of row.names=1 so that 'var1', 'var2', ... are stored as row names
# instead of being read as data values.
# - the computation of the independent variable 'years'
# (used as x in the function to optimize) from the column names read
# (so that we do not hardcode its values, but read them from the input data instead)
survieF <- read.csv("SurvieF.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE), row.names=1)
years <- as.numeric( substring( names(survieF), 2 ) )

#--- 2) Define the function to optimize that also defines the model to fit
# Note that two parameters were added, 'S' and 'x', so that:
# - we can pass the value of S as every row of survieF via apply() below
# - the function is fully self-contained (in the previous version,
# one needs to "magically" know that object x needs to be defined
# already in order for the function to work properly)
f <- function(ab,S,x){
  a <- ab[1]
  b <- ab[2]
  return(sum((exp(a*x**b)-S)**2))
}

#--- 3) Obtain the estimated parameters for each row of survieF
opt_params <- apply(survieF, 1, function(S,years) { 
                                    nlm(f,p=c(1,0),S,years)$estimate
                                }, years)
```

whose output is:

```
          var1      var2      var3
[1,] -39.68255 -39.73691 -41.63971
[2,] -51.56907 -51.42185 -53.87351
```

You can then follow a similar strategy to obtain the predicted values for the years 1 thru 20 for every variable `var1`, `var2`, `var3`.